# как автоматом залить csv файл в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Здравствуйте.
На сервере сайта есть **CSV** файлик с выгруженной базой. Как ее можно автоматом залить в таблицу на **MySQL**? Пока делаю руками через **phpMyAdmin**, удаляю старую, импортирую новую.
Пытался через **php** страницу с кодом **Load Data** и файл загрузить данные, но на хостинге написано отключена такая команда.
Как может еще можно автоматизировать этот процесс?

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать скрипт для импорта. Скрипт принимает файл, парсит csv построчно и записывает данные в MySQL.

Comment: но это получается также надо на каком-либо языке программирования писать, типа php?

Comment: да. можно и на PHP.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать чуть более развёрнутые ответы

Answer (score 0):

Может пригодится.

Я иногда загружаю CSV файл с DEF кодами(который лежит на сайте Россвязи) в БД `asterisk` с помощью BASH и crontab:

```
//Clear

mysql asterisk -e "TRUNCATE TABLE def_all;"

//Fill

mysql asterisk -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/Kody_DEF-9kh.csv' INTO TABLE def_all CHARACTER SET CP1251 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```

Поля в БД соответствуют полям в CSV файле для удобства выгрузки....

Comment: у меня на хостинге как я понял есть только планировщик задач cron, это не то?

Comment: Да cron пригодится для автоматизации процесса. ssh  доступ есть на хостинг?

Comment: да, он есть на хостинге

Comment: Терь надо залогинится по ssh и проверить доступны ли команды типа mysql, crontab, wget на хостинге...

Comment: получается мне надо попробовать залезть по SSH на хостинг и попробовать ввести эти команды в командной строке?

Comment: Да именно так!!!1 А что у Вас за хостинг? Выделенный виртуальный сервер? Если что можно установить необходимые пакеты...

Comment: нет, не выделенный, обычный виртуальный хостинг